# "Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully" after WTSQueryUserToken on 32bit Windows (64bit works)

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop, win32exception

I'm developing a small Windows Service in C# that needs to do interop with Win32 API at some point. I'm getting the following exception which does not make sense to me:

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully`

Right after the last line in this C# snippet:

```
var sessionId = Kernel32.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
var userTokenPtr = new IntPtr();
if (!WtsApi32.WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, out userTokenPtr))
{
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Here's how I'm declaring `WTSQueryUserToken` in `WtsApi32`:

```
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll", EntryPoint="WTSQueryUserToken")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken
(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)] ulong sessionId, 
    [Out] out IntPtr phToken
);
```

Some facts:

- This works perfectly on 64bit Win7, but **fails on a 32bit Win7**.
- There's no way the [10,000 handle limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327699) has been reached when this is executed, it's the first Win32 call in a very small windows service.
- I think there might be some underlying Win32 error but some bug overwrote the errorcode with a 0, thus giving me the "success" error message, but I don't know how to confirm or even diagnose this.
- When I catch the exception, sessionId is 1 and userTokenPtr is 0. However, GetLastError returns 0 so I have no idea what happened.
- **Nearly all of the answers I found to this problem had to do with [improper disposal of user controls](http://nomagichere.blogspot.com.ar/2008/03/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception-is.html). Since this is a Windows service, *this is not the case*.**

I'm guessing there must be something wrong with my WTSQueryUserToken declaration, since it only fails on 32bit Windows, which leads me to think it's a marshaling problem. However, I still can't see what it might be.

Comment: `bool` is not the same as `BOOL` as far as I know. I think their size differs. You certain that prototype for C# is correct in that light?

Comment: It works on x64, that's all the certainty I have so far. :) Or maybe it's not the x64/x86 difference but something else that's breaking it. I'm looking into it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sessionId parameter us defined as a c# ulong - an unsigned 64-bit integer, whereas the actual function export is expecting a Win32 ulong - an unsigned 32-bit integer.

[c# ulong data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Win32 data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#LONG)

Comment: It works, thank you so much! Actually I had thought of this and tried `UnmanagedType.U4` to fix it, but it seems that it was changing `ulong` to `UInt32` that did the trick. The line now reads:             `[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 sessionId`.

Comment: 64bit vs 32bit can be tricky sometimes.  Glad the fix was so easy this time.